# Why won't my Yongnuo YN-560-TX trigger power on correctly?

Tags: flash, yongnuo, wireless-triggers

When I turn on my Yongnuo YN-560-TX flash trigger it gets stuck on the power-on loading screen. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Did you try different batteries?

Answer (score 0):

It's Yongnuo.

In other words, it's a disposable piece of... gear.

Sometimes Yongnuo devices last for many years. Usually they fail within a year of two.

I've got a single YN685 that still works seven years since I bought it, though it has gotten fairly light use over the past 3-4 years as I've moved to Godox/Flashpoint (I use a Godox X1-R on the hot foot of the flash to control it with a Godox transmitter when I need a third flash).

Two YN-622 transceivers were still working after about three years of moderate use when I moved to Godox/Flashpoint, but they've been sitting on a shelf for several years now. I have no idea if they still would work.

I've also got a small pile of other YN flashes, mostly YN-568EX II, that barely lasted a year each.

I've got a YN35mm f/2 lens for EF mount that lasted three day-long shooting sessions using it maybe 10% of the time at each before it no longer will stop down. Since it's hopelessly soft wide open, it's now useless. It's not even heavy enough to be a paperweight.